# How to avoid this segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to separate strings from a string by using whitespace but unfortunately I am getting segmentation fault error in C. However, it is working fine when you pass a string with space e.g. "Hello World" but not working when I pass string with 2 spaces i.e "h e r".

I don't understand where I am wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* yoda(char n1[20])
{
    int i,j,t=0,k=2,len,c=0;
    len=strlen(n1);
    char n2[20];
    char* n3[20];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(n1[i]==' ')
        c++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<c+1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(k==0)
            {
                if(n1[t+1]==' ')
                {

                    t++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    n2[j]=n1[t+1];  
                    t++;
                }
            }
            else if(n1[j]==' ')
            {
                t=j;
                k=0;
                break;  
            }
            else
            {
                k=1;
                n2[j]=n1[j];
            }
        }
        strcpy(n3[i],n2);
    }
    for(i=0;i<c+1;i++)
    {
        //for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            printf("\n%s",n3[i]);
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    char sen[20],res[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",sen);
    //printf("%s",
    yoda(sen);
}
```

Comment: First glance: your function takes a `char*` and you are feeding it `int*`... Get a modern compiler and turn on warnings. Signature of `main` is `int main(void) {}`.

Comment: `strcpy(n3[i],n2);`: no memoy is allocated for `n3[i]`, hence seg fault. (And they are not initialized so point to random locations.)

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read lines of user input; or at the very least, use a width limitation (`"%20[^\n]"`) if you insist on using `scanf()`. Oh, that trailing `s` is actually trying to match against a literal `s`, as the conversion specifier is `%[]`, period. And **do** check `scanf()` return value. Anything else is flirting with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Another stylistic nitpick, since C99 you no longer have to declare all your variables at the beginning of a function; you can declare them right where you need them (e.g. `for ( size_t i = 0; ... )`). This usually makes for more readable code, and avoids "unused variable" warnings when you restructure things.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help and suggestions. I am new here i will try to use above suggestions to write code better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here **segmentation fault**  occurred due to not allocating memory for `char *n3[20];` .
In the statement  `strcpy(n3[i],n2);` , `n3[i]` is not allocated to any memory space.You have to dynamically allocate memory for  `n3[i]` using dynamic memory allocation.

Also your conditions like `i<c+1` can be replaced simpler condition `i<=c` ;. You have too many `for-loops` in your code which makes your code **unreadable**.You also do not have returned any value from `char* yoda(char n1[20])`;. You forgotten to use `\0` to denote end-of-string `n2` before `strcpy(n3[i],n2);`.

I have `re-written` your code with lesser `for-loops` . Try this :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *yoda(char *n1)        // modified function.
{
    int i, j, k, c = 0;
    char n2[20];
    char *n3[20];

    for (j = 0, k = 0;; j++)
    {
        if (n1[j] != ' ' && n1[j] != '\0')
        {
            n2[k++] = n1[j];
        }
        else
        {
            n2[k] = '\0';
            n3[c] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(n2)); // dynamic memory allocation
            strcpy(n3[c], n2);
            c++;
            k = 0;
        }

        if (n1[j] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        {
            printf("\n%s", n3[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    char sen[20], res[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", sen);
    //printf("%s",
    yoda(sen);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
I Love you C

I
Love
you
C
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anoop, Next time for sure i will remember everything that i forgot. Thanks again for your suggestions & help.